# How set dynamic approval on YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I've a project in Azure Devops, and into the project I've several repos.
For example:

- the repos that begin with "A" have their release approval group.
- the repos that begin with "B" have their release approval group.
- etc.

I've a YAML piepline with a Build stage and release stage.
I have to set the release approval dynamically, based on repository.
exists a method without create several Environments?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit for the scenario? Do you already have `approval and check` on the repos?What do you mean of `set the release approval dynamically, based on repository`, what's the relationship between the repos and release stages? If you have already part of the yaml, please share it in your statement for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can set approvals and checks on repositories themselves.

1. Navigate to `Project Settings`
2. Select `Repositories`
3. Click on the Repository you wish to add a check too
4. Switch to the `Approvals and Checks` tab
5. Click the `+` button
6. Configure the approvals to your desire
7. Repeat for each repository

[image]

There is no way to automatically approvals and checks to all repositories that start with a certain letter. You will need to configure this manually per repository.

It may help you to create permission groups, and then assign a group as the approver to a repository, for example you can have a group named `approvers-for-repositories-that-start-with-a` and another named `approvers-for-repositories-that-start-with-b`.

These can be created in the Permissions section of Project Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you check the repos for your release pipeline, but if you only would like target group to approve the deployment, you can consider to use [manual validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops#set-up-manual-validation) **instead** of `approve and checks` on repositories and environments.

Steps below:

1. Determine which repo is used and set the variable accordingly.
2. Based on the repo name, use `manual validation` to ask approve for target users/group.
3. Run the deployment based on the approve result.

My yaml script for your reference:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories: 
  - repository: AstartedRepo
    name: 'A1Repo'
    type: git
    trigger: 
     branches:
      include:
        - main
        - dev1

  - repository: BstartedRepo
    name: 'B1Repo'
    type: git
    trigger: 
     branches:
      include:
        - main
        - dev1

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
    - job: job1
      steps:
        - script: echo this is Build stage......

- stage: Release
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
    - job: job1
      displayName: Check the repo name
      steps:
        - bash: |
            if [[ "${REPO_NAME}" == "A1Repo" ]]; then
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=reponame;isOutput=true]A1Repo"
            elif [[ "${REPO_NAME}" == "B1Repo" ]]; then
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=reponame;isOutput=true]B1Repo"
            else
              echo "Unknown repository"
            fi
          env:
            REPO_NAME: $(Build.Repository.Name)
          name: repocheck
    
    - job: waitForValidationforGroup1
      displayName: Wait for external validation
      dependsOn: job1
      variables:
        repo: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['repocheck.reponame'] ]
      condition: startsWith(variables['repo'], 'A') 
      pool: server    
      steps:   
      - task: ManualValidation@0
        timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
        inputs:
          notifyUsers: 'testaccount1@hotxxil.com'
          instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
    
    - job: waitForValidationforGroup2
      displayName: Wait for external validation  
      dependsOn: job1
      variables:
        repo: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['repocheck.reponame'] ]
      condition: startsWith(variables['repo'], 'B')  
      pool: server    
      steps:   
      - task: ManualValidation@0
        timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
        inputs:
          notifyUsers: 'testaccount2@hoxxail.com'
          instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'

  
    - deployment: Deploy
      displayName: deploy job
      dependsOn: 
        - waitForValidationforGroup1
        - waitForValidationforGroup2
      condition: |
        or(
          eq(dependencies.waitForValidationforGroup1.result, 'Succeeded'), 
          eq(dependencies.waitForValidationforGroup2.result, 'Succeeded')
        )
      environment: 'Verify'
      strategy:
        # default deployment strategy, more coming...
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - script: echo my first deployment
```

Approve to deploy:

[image]

Reject and not deploy:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it dosen't works on self hosted agent :(

Comment: Checked on my side, no matter it's Microsoft-hosted or Self-hosted agent, it works fine, as it uses the `agentless` job `manual validation` for approval. You can share the current yaml and error detail, so that we can help further.